# How do I make a custom element available globally in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to update an app based in pluralsight course "Building Applications with Aurelia" with methods to make a custom component globally available to DOM.

The course still has globalizeResources because it was written before 0.15 or whatnot and hasn't been updated.

Note that <require> does work to display the custom component contained in resources...

none of these methods seem to:

in main.js:

```
 aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .globalResources("./resources/nav-menu");
```

or

```
 aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .feature("resources");
```

with ./resources/index.js containing

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.globalResources("./nav-menu");
}
```

or

```
 aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin("./resources/nav-menu");
```

Has this changed again, or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which chapter of the course you use, but this is taken from the 5th chapter. Didn't follow the course, but it shows Movies and then the nav :-)

See this gistrun for a working example:

https://gist.run/?id=ef855f42433dd22c533e1f52e48dfc45

(run it in chrome, for best gistrun support)

Comment: Thank you, yes chapter 5. I pasted in your solution and I get the same result as before. Is there anything I need to import or update I wonder... jspm update- no change.

Comment: I don't know how much of it will still align to the course, but it is probably best to just get a copy of the aurelia skeleton for aspnet core and copy over file by file. jspm upgrade will probably not update you to the latest bits (you need to manual set them from github to npm for sure). Did you look at the aurelia fundamentals course by Brain Noyes? It's from may 2016, using the 1.0.0 beta bits, that closer to today.

Comment: I did go after that other course and built the corresponding app for custom elements. I got the sample app running but did not get an understanding of what was significant to getting it working. Since then I started building off the github aurelia cli and that is quite different as well. Moving target.